# Unable to locate and replace an element with its classname using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to write bash script for search, copy and paste an element by its class name. I am quite new to bash. Can anybody help me or give me a suggestion?

For example,

```
<div class="elementOne">..</div>
<div class="elementTwo">
   <div class="SubelementOne">....</div>
   <div class="SubelementTwo">....</div>
</div>
```

I want to select "SubelementTwo" and put it under "elementOne"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First turn your HTML into XHTML, then do any modifications you want with an XML tool.

If you have an input like this:

```
$ cat foo
<div class="elementOne">..</div>
<div class="elementTwo">
   <div class="SubelementOne">....</div>
   <div class="SubelementTwo">....</div>
</div>
```

Clean it up into valid XHTML with `tidy` and then easily move elements with class `SubelementTwo` under an element with class `elementOne`:

```
$ tidy -asxhtml foo 2>/dev/null | \
    xmlstarlet ed -m '//*[@class="SubelementTwo"]' '//*[@class="elementOne"]'

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Linux version 5.2.0"/>
    <title/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="elementOne">..<div class="SubelementTwo">....</div></div>
    <div class="elementTwo">
      <div class="SubelementOne">....</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is more robust than [regex based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) solutions.